$n$-th layer of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension, $K_n=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n}+{\zeta_{p^n}}^{-1})$
Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $K_n=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n}+{\zeta_{p^n}}^{-1})$.
In the notation $3.1$ of the paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.16785), the paper reads $K_n$ is called the n-th layer of cyclic $\Bbb{Z}_p$ extension.
But I think direct limit of $\mathrm{Gal}(K_n/\Bbb{Q})$ is not $\Bbb{Z}_p$ because $\mathrm{Gal}(K_n/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\times/\{\pm1\}$.
What does it mean that $K_n$ is the $n$-th layer of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension?

Ah, I see where the confusion comes from. It's quite simple, really. The thing is the author of the cited paper had a momentary brain freeze (I can say that with confidence since I wrote the paper haha).
You're absolutely right. What I actually meant was: consider the (cyclotomic) $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and write $K_n$ for its unique subfield of degree $p^n$.

@Locally unskillful   I didn't expect to receive a reply from the paper's author. MathStackExchange is truly an excellent site! Your result is both fascinating and very powerful - I am studying your paper in a seminar with my professor at university. Looking forward to future interactions.

Hello there. I noticed Math Stack Exchange doesn’t have private messaging. I found your comment really interesting!
If you’d like to chat, feel free to email me—my address is on the last page of my paper.
Looking forward to hearing from you!
